# Flex SFDC integration

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, salesforce

I have downloaded 'Adobe Flash builder for Force.com' from Salesforce site and trying to get some hands on. If any one has tried it before request you to please share your experience. Rt now I am referring to Salesforce documentations available at 'http://developer.force.com/flashbuilder' which is pretty good. But, if there are any other demos/articles available on the topic, including step-by-step guide for new sfdc project creation in flash builder, please share them with me.

Comment: They're giving a webinar soon, maybe you'd like to register for it :) https://www.developerforce.com/events/flash_builder_webinar/registration.php?d=70130000000FNWq

Answer (score 0):

Check out my article and video on [Building Client / Cloud Apps with Flash Builder for Force.com](http://www.jamesward.com/2010/07/26/building-client-cloud-apps-with-flash-builder-for-force-com/).